# question on the output of double value

Tags: java

In the code, I have

```
int a = 62;
int b = 132;
double c;
c = (double) a/b;
System.out.println(c);
```

which prints out the value of c as  0.469696968793869
How can I just keep a short format for c, like 0.4697

Comment: Not sure what JVM you are using, but that's not the correct output.  It should output 0.0 (not 0.469696968793869) since we are talking about integer division.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to cast it. I have edited the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to **keep** (not print) a result of prescribed precision is to use the java.math.BigDecimal class as follows.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class Foo {

    private static final int PRECISION = 5;
    private static final MathContext MATH_CONTEXT = new MathContext(PRECISION, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    public static void main(String... args) {
        double a = 62;
        double b = 132; // Doubles used to avoid integer division truncation
        final BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal(a / b, MATH_CONTEXT);
        System.out.println(c); // Prints 0.46970
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
 System.out.print(df.format(c));
```

`#.####` to keep four decimal places but trailing zeros would be ignored. If you want to four decimal places including any trailing zeros, use format string `#.0000` instead.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is `NumberFormat`.

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");
String s = formatter.format(c);
System.out.println(s);
```

(The 0 symbol shows a digit or 0 if no digit present.)

See [this page](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/FormatNum.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
System.out.format("%.4f%n", c);
```

Or:

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(".####");
String output = myFormatter.format(c);
System.out.println(output);
```

See [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) Java tutorial for more details.

Comment: If I not only want to just output C in the shorter format, but also want to save C in this shorter format, can I still use this way? It seems to me that DecimalFormat transforms the double value into the string format.

Comment: You can do this: `double cshort = Double.parseDouble(output);`.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.printf("%.4f%n", c);
```